# Extracting the value of an element from Dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R and trying to extract a specific element from a data frame and compare it with an integer.

I had a table saved in text file.

[image: data-file image]

I used the following to read the table.

```
mydata = read.table("file.txt");
```

In my case I want to compare an element say, say the first element of USERPOR (which is 1.0) with an  integer 1.0 (so the comparison should return true).

The code I wrote was

```
mydata[[2,7]]

[1] 1.000
Levels: 1.000 10.0000 2.000 3.000 4.00 5.00 6.000 7.000 8.000 9.000 USERPROR
```

However, when I compared them, I got 'FALSE'. Can anybody tell why is that so?

```
> mydata[[2,7]]==1.0

[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmmm. First, elements of a data.frame are ordinarily accessed using *single* brackets -- like `mydata[2,7]`. Double brackets will access a column, e.g. `mydata[[2]]` will return the second column. Thus, `mydata[[7]][2]` is the same as `mydata[2,7]`.

Second, since your output includes a `Levels:` list, it appears that that variable is stored as a factor having levels of `"1.000"`, `"10.0000"`, ... `"USERPROR"` (odd enough that I'm guessing the data are entered incorrectly). Accordingly, I believe that in your example, `mydata[2,7] == "1.000"` would return `TRUE`.

In general, if you want to compare a numeric value with an integer, don't use a comparison value like `1.0`, because thje `.0` part forces it to be stored as floating-point, not integer. If the data are stored as floating-point, there may be enough roundoff that a number computed as `1.0` is not exactly equal to an integer `1`. The reliable way to test it is to use `round(mydata[2,7]) == 1`.

Comment: I tried round(mydata[2,7]) == 1. It is giving me the following error.

Error in Math.factor(1L) : round not meaningful for factors.

Please see my edited question.

Comment: *Right*. That's because what you have there is a factor, like I stated earlier - not a floating-point value. I repeat, I think your first issue is that the data are not stored correctly. Get the data in there right first -- otherwise, it's garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Here's the problem. Using `read.table` to read the data, but include the argument `header=TRUE`. It appears the variable names are being included as part of the data.

Comment: Yes "header=true" fixed the problem. So the actual issue was the way the data was read. Thank you so much! I literally spent hours on this.

Comment: Good. I don't know why they defaulted to `header=FALSE` in `read.table`, but they did.